# GROK regex capture groups not matching

Tags: regex, logstash, grok

I'm trying to learn how to capture different fields in a log file using logstash's grok filter for the first time and having trouble parsing it correctly. I'm using https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to test my work. This is an example log file:

```
06/05/2021 15:08:48.591 - [aa.bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.cccccccccc.ddddddd.EEEeeeEeeeeEeeeeee.ffffFffffFff] - [INFO] - some more text here (0:1): {"data":{"source":"ttyUSB0","timeTotal":"20","timeLeft":"10"},"somethingid":"main","secret":"aqdsaqlaxgaaaaaa444aa32aa1aa3aaa1aaaaaaawghhjuyeqbbjjga7a64aaa","type":"TEST","message":"SOMEMESSAGE","testid":"foo.bar1.1620313718583","timestamp":1620313728590}
```

The grok expression I'm using (**and returns no result**) is

```
%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} - (?<test_data>(?<=\[)([a-zA-Z\.\[\]])*) - (?<rest>(?<=\[)(\[(\w*)\]))
```

When I remove the lookbehind expression `(?<=\[)` from `(?<test_data>(?<=\[)([a-zA-Z\.\[\]])*)` and `(?<rest>(?<=\[)(\[(\w*)\]))` I get the following result:

- `test_data: [aa.bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.cccccccccc.ddddddd.EEEeeeEeeeeEeeeeee.ffffFffffFff]`
- `rest: [INFO]`

The result I'm hoping to get is:

- `test_data: aa.bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.cccccccccc.ddddddd.EEEeeeEeeeeEeeeeee.ffffFffffFff`
- `rest: INFO`

Would appreciate help / explanation on what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are matching a *sequence* of patterns, so you need to *consume* them, otherwise the regex engine cannot reach the subsequent (rightmost) pattern parts.

Lookarounds are not consuming patterns, they simply check the context at some location. So,  `(?<=\[)` is a pattern that will never match since a space cannot be a `[` char at the same time. This is why the pattern you have is not working.

You can use

```
%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} - \[%{DATA:test_data}\] - \[%{DATA:rest}\]
```

Now, the regex engine will find the `timestamp` pattern, then it will consume space+`-`+space, then a `[` char, then `test_data`, `] - [`, the `rest` part and a `]` char.